# If $Sp\{v_1,v_2\}=Sp\{w_1,w_2\}$, can I make this assumption?

Tags: linear-algebra

So given $Sp\{v_1,v_2\}=Sp\{w_1,w_2\}$,

Can I assume $v_1$ is a linear combination of vectors from $\{w_1, w_2\}$?

If so, can I assume for instance that -

$v_1 = \lambda_1w_1 + \lambda_2w_2$

Can I assume that if $\lambda_1=0$ then $\lambda_2\ne0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, yes and no. Since $v_1$ can be $0$ we may have $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$.

Comment: And even if $v_1\neq 0$, we can't assume that $\lambda_1=0$. $\lambda_1=0$ means that $v_1$ and $w_2$ are parallel.